# GroupBy and Return a List of List

Tags: c#

Given a GroupBy

```
var result = _bucket
      .GroupBy(x => x)
      .Select(x => x.First())
      .ToList();
```

This is what i achieved and returns only the first group. But I would like to return all the Groups as a `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: `.Select(x => x.ToList())`

Comment: if you are using VS, then it allows to view type of object in LINQ queries... so you can check what is type of `x` in `.Select` and select waht you need

Comment: "possible in 1 statement" should not be a requirement.

Comment: Removed the requirement

Comment: I just noticed. If I call groupBy in a loop with First() i get different results as when i group only once with ToList(). Is that normal ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need it in List<List>,
you need to convert it into nested list.
The simplest way is to do this ->

```
var result = _bucket
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

This should resolve your query

Comment: "into list twice" - That's not a very good description.

Comment: what I meant was to convert into nested list. My bad. I'll edit it.

Comment: What do you mean with "into list twice" ?

Comment: That's much better.